# javascript to hide a div if the div has no content

Tags: javascript

Due to client request, i am unable to use jquery. I am using below script to check if a div is empty and then hide it if so. Not working though. Any ideas?

```
<style>     
#top
{
padding: 0;
height: 120px;
width: 820px;
float: left;
background: #cccccc;
}
</style>
        <script>
if( document.getElementById("top").innerHTML == "" )
{
   document.getElementById("top").style.display='none';
}
        </script>
        <div id="top">
        </div>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle testcase? it should work..

Comment: does the div content change dynamically?

Comment: @Nelson: Not as shown it shouldn't.

Comment: Your browser has a built-in debugger. If you look in the debugger, you will see an error telling you what's wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Move the `script` *after* the `div`

```
<style>
    #top {
        padding: 0;
        height: 120px;
        width: 820px;
        float: left;
        background: #cccccc;
    }
</style>
<div id="top"></div>
<script>
    if (document.getElementById("top").innerHTML == "") {
        document.getElementById("top").style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Check this fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/kJcfY/

Based on the (valuable) comments:

Here is a variation of the functionality you are trying to achieve:
(This would take care of the stray whitespaces)

```
if (typeof (String.prototype.trim) === "undefined") {
    String.prototype.trim = function () {
        return String(this).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    };
}

$top = document.getElementById("top");
if ($top.innerHTML.trim() == "") {
    $top.style.display = 'none';
}
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/kJcfY/1/

Comment: And probably get rid of the redundant lookup?

Comment: Or put it in a `window.onload = function(){};`.

Comment: keeping the `</div>` in the same line as `<div id="top">` did the trick here (since a new line counts as a character), not the position of the `script`

Answer (score 1):

You should trim the content of div before comparing if it is null. check this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.getElementById("top").innerHTML.trim()=='')
{
   alert('hello');
   document.getElementById("top").style.display='none';
}
</script>
```

It should work have a try..

Comment: Really appreciate the help. Is there anyway to prevent the code showing for the split second before the script hides it?

Comment: Hi! Sorry i didn't get you. Can you please elaborate your question.

Comment: As the script is after the div, you see the empty div with coloured background for a split second before the script hides it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already moved the ending `div`-Tag to the same line than the opening one. This was a part of your problem.

Please try to compare empty strings with the `===` Operator, it will save you some hazzle.